# If two things are not not equal, are they equal?

Tags: types, proof, agda, dependent-type

If two values in Agda, or some other dependently typed language, you can prove that `v₁` is not not equal to `v₂`, can you prove `v₁` equals `v₂`?

Like, is there a function of the type `((v₁ ≡ v₂ → ⊥) → ⊥) → v₁ ≡ v₂`?

This seems like something that is safe to add as axiom if it can't be proven, since there can be at most one value of `v₁ ≡ v₂`.

A reason this is interesting is that double negation (`(a → ⊥) → ⊥`) forms a [monad](/questions/tagged/monad). Usually you can't extract values from it, but you can certain values, like `⊥` from it (if you derive a contradiction in classical logic monad, you have a contradiction). I was wondering if equality was a thing that could be extracted.

Comment: I think it's provable in Observational Type Theory, but even if it's not, you can postulate there anything equality related without breaking computational properties of the system.

Answer (score 7):

Double negation elimination is unprovable in intuitionistic type theory, as chi presented here, but its negation is also unprovable, so it can be assumed consistently.

However, while classical axioms aren't provable for all types, they are provable for decidable types. Decidable types are those which are provably inhabited or uninhabited:

```
Decidable : Type -> Type
Decidable A = Either A (A -> False)
```

Given `Decidable A`, one can implement double negation elimination on `A`: just pattern match on `Either A (A -> False)`, and if we get an `A`, then we're done, if we get `A -> False`, then we apply `(A -> False) -> False` and use ex falso.

As a special case `((a = b -> False) -> False) -> a = b` is provable if `(a b : A) -> Decidable (a = b)`, i. e. `A` has decidable equality.

As to the `(A -> False) -> False` continuation monad, when we work inside this monad we get some form of classical reasoning, since monadic join here corresponds to "quadruple" negation elimination, so `not (not (not (not A))) -> not (not A))`. We can also use `callCC`, which corresponds to [Peirce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law), another classical statement.

There's an interesting observation about this: we can take any classical proof, lift all propositions to `Cont False` (in other words, double negate them), and we get a corresponding constructive proof that proves the double negation of the original proposition. This means that constructive logic can prove everything classical logic can, modulo classical logical equivalence, since a proposition and its double negation are classically equivalent.

Comment: I had an idea for a programming language, where proofs need to be constructive, but classical proofs can be embedded in a monad. This way, classical proofs can be used for things where constructiveness isn't needed.

Answer (score 6):

I think that law is not provable in Agda or Coq.

Roughly, we only have one hypothesis

```
(v1 = v2 -> False) -> False
```

and we need to prove the thesis `v1 = v2`.

Consider a cut-free proof of that in a sequent-based proof system. What would the last rule be?

It can not be an introduction of `v1 = v2`, because `Refl` has not that type (`v1,v2` are distinct variables).

So, it must be an elimination of the hypothesis, i.e.

```
H1: (v1 = v2 -> False) -> False |- v1 = v2 -> False
H2: (v1 = v2 -> False) -> False , False |- v1 = v2
---------------------------------------------------  (->E)
(v1 = v2 -> False) -> False |- v1 = v2
```

However, if `H1` is indeed provable, we must also have

```
(v1 = v2 -> False) -> False |- False
```

from which we derive

```
|- ((v1 = v2 -> False) -> False) -> False
```

which is equivalent to

```
|- v1 = v2 -> False
```

which is clearly not provable without any other assumptions on `v1,v2`. Indeed, otherwise we could generalize that to

```
|- forall v1 v2, v1 = v2 -> False
```

which is clearly wrong.

On the other hand, I believe that Agda/Coq/... are consistent with the Law of Excluded Middle, which implies the proposed law. Hence, the law can not violate consistency.